# How to identify element using following-sibling method in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, automation

Following code I need to identify third **li** element(user list). How I co do using selenium?

I have tried using,

```
String usertype= //td[text()='product']
String usersubtype= li[@class='user-list dropbutton-action secondary-action']

String adduser = usertype +"following-sibling::td//" +usersubtype+"/a"
```

I must use **following** method. Because my code ***usertype*** and ***usersubtype*** values coming from different place

(above strings just for reference)

But it could not work out. Please help me to identify the third **li** element(user list)

I need to identify **following** element in the code

```
<li class="content-list dropbutton-action secondary-action"><a href="/admin/structure/eck/entity/product">User list</a></li>
```

Below is my code snippet:

```
<tr class="even">
<td>product</td>
<td>product</td>
<td>
    <div class="code-wrapper dropbutton-multiple">
        <div class="dropbutton-widget">
            <ul class="dropbutton">
                <li class="user dropbutton-action"><a href="/user/userlist/abc/productcontent/add">Add User</a></li>
                <li class="dropbutton-toggle"><button type="button"><span class="dropbutton-arrow"><span class="visually-hidden">List actions</span></span></button></li>
                <li class="user-list dropbutton-action secondary-action"><a href="/user/userlist/abc/productproduct">User list</a></li>
                <li class="user-list dropbutton-action secondary-action"><a href="/user/userlist/abc/productproduct/types">Test list</a></li>
                <li class="edit dropbutton-action"><a href="/user/userlist/abc/productmanage/product?destination=/admin/structure/eck/entity_type">Edit</a></li>
                <li class="delete dropbutton-action"><a href="/user/userlist/abc/productmanage/product/delete?destination=/admin/structure/eck/entity_type">Delete</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your locator is that it is incorrect. The double slash is missing from the `following-sibling::`.

**Try changing:**

```
//td[text()='product']following-sibling::td//li[@class='user-list dropbutton-action secondary-action']
```

**To**

```
//td[text()='product']//following-sibling::td//li[@class='user-list dropbutton-action secondary-action']/a
```

**Complete code:**

```
String usertype= //td[text()='product']
String usersubtype= li[@class='user-list dropbutton-action secondary-action']

String adduser = usertype +"//following-sibling::td//" +usersubtype+"/a"
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Comment: Thank you. But I need click the href element under that li tag . its hidden one. Whenever i'm trying to click it says ,

<a href="/user/userlist/abc/productproduct" type displayed:false</a>
due to this i'm unable to click the element.

But when i use this xpath i must get value as "<a href="/user/userlist/abc/productproduct" type> User list</a>

then only i can click that element.

Comment: @ManojSoundarrajan Can you please share your complete code like how you are clicking the element etc and if possible can you please provide steps to steps use case for this scenario. I didn't get what you want to say and achieve in this case.

Comment: I resolved this Bro. Thanks for help. This element comes under one drop down option
//td[text()='product']//following-sibling::td//li[@class='user-list dropbutton-action secondary-action']/a
So when I try to click this element directly, it didn't work put. Because  <<<< displayed:false >>>>. Element hidden under dropdown fields. So what I did first I clicked that dropdown button then identified, above mentioned element. Its working fine now. Thanks for your help. Your answer is most suitable so I mark your answer as acceptable. Please accept my request in linkedin :)

Comment: @ManojSoundarrajan Sure, Thanks bro 

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply:

```
//li[contains(@class,'content-list')]
```

or with css selector

```
li.content-list
```

?

Comment: Or you have to add more details to make it more precise ?

Comment: I must use following method. Because i'm adding two values to make the locator in my code. Added more details in the code